# BaseAdapter getView giving multiple convertview objects for a single position

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I have a ListView inside of a fragment in a sliding tab view. I created a custom adapter for the listview that extends BaseAdapter. The issue is that when I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` getView then gets called a few times (OK) but only on the last call is the `convertView` parameter valid. On the first few calls it gives a valid (non-null) view object but it is not the view that is actually being displayed. I know this is true because updates to the invalid `convertViews` do not show up on the screen. SensorViewHolder is the private static viewholder class. I know there is only one instance of the adapter because the adapter object's ID is not changing, which also means I can be sure there is only one fragment in the sliding tab view. The reason this is an issue is because once I use multiple list items with this adapter, `setBackground()` no longer works, even though the other items (a few TextViews) are able to set their text without any issue.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "View updating...");
    View vi = convertView;
    SensorViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new SensorViewHolder();
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_sensor, null);
        holder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tab_sensor_name);
        holder.weight = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tab_sensor_weight);
        holder.unit = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tab_sensor_unit);
        holder.selectionLayout = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.tab_sensor_selection);
        holder.onSelectListener = new OnSelectListener(position);
        holder.selectionLayout.setOnTouchListener(holder.onSelectListener);
    } else
        holder =(SensorViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    vi.setTag(holder);
    if (prevSelected != selected) {
            if (position == selected)
                holder.selectionLayout.setBackground(bgSelected);
            else
                holder.selectionLayout.setBackground(bgUnselected);
    }
    if (position == getCount() - 1)
            prevSelected = selected;
    // update rest of components
    return vi;
}
```

EDIT: I looked into this more and found that the invalid views were both invalidated and dirty. Why would `getView()` be giving me dirty, invalidated views?

Comment: I am not sure about this but I think that it might be the case that it will go once in the prevSelected != selected if and then it sets the background to something and after that you don't have an else statement to reset that background for the other case when the prevSelected == selected..

Comment: What do you mean by invalidated/dirty ?

Comment: @Cata I print out `convertView.toString()` to the log and the dirty and invalidated flags are set. (Line 4582-4583 of View.java)

Comment: That should be because of the view recycling I guess, that is why I said that a good practice when you have an if statement in getView() is to always have also an else where you reset the view to the initial state. Otherwise the same view will be returned next time and UI glitches will appear

Comment: @Cata This does happen, `if (prevSelected != selected)` will get called once for each position before this condition returns false via updating prevSelected.